# What's the use of bones in a 2D skeletal animation?

Tags: java, 2d, skeletal-animation, bones

I'm trying to implement a renderer using a scene graph and skeletal animation. As far as I know the bones in a skeletal animation just represent a connection between two joints. However, if a Joint knows its parent- and child-Joints what would you even need bones for?

Also, why would you need a separate class, Skeleton to represent a 2D entity (whatsoever) when the Skeleton is just an array of joints? Isn't that just a waste of memory? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you need edges in a  graph structure when nodes know their connections to other nodes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your particular implementation it is hard to say, but in general a "bone" is just another term for either a "joint" (a 3D position that will be animated) or a "joint plus reference to the parent joint."

This

> However, if a Joint knows its parent- and child-Joints what would you
>   even need bones for?

implies to me that you're using the latter definition in your system (have joints which know their parent) and thus "bone" is just another term for what you already have.

> Also, why would you need a separate class, Skeleton to represent a 2D
>   entity (whatsoever) when the Skeleton is just an array of joints?

It sounds like you're asking why you'd want to have

```
struct Skeleton {
  Array<Joint> bones;
};
```

instead of

```
Array<Joint> skeleton;
```

If that's the case, it's generally for the same reason you'd want to have a structure for a 3D vector instead of passing three floats everywhere. It encapsulates the logical concept you're trying to express, improving readability to some degree and providing you a place to hook various related functionality (such as, perhaps, updating all the joints in the skeleton with new positions based on some input animation data).